# How to check if the node is deleted or not in linked list

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

Hey please someone clear my doubt, if I delete a node and later I try to print the data of that node what should be the output? How to check if the node is deleted or not?

In this program I am trying to delete duplicate nodes and how to know if I deleted them correctly! I thought after deleting a node if I try to access that deleted node's data I will get zero if everything went correctly! But it's the case here, so I tried counting nodes again and it's good. Is counting the only way to check?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct dll {
    int data;
    struct dll* next;
} dll;

int main() {
    dll* p1, *p2, *p3, *p4, *p5, *temp, *head, *todel, *cur, *fwd, *dup;
    int count = 0, i = 0, j = 0;

    p1 = (dll*)malloc(sizeof(dll));
    p2 = (dll*)malloc(sizeof(dll));
    p3 = (dll*)malloc(sizeof(dll));
    p4 = (dll*)malloc(sizeof(dll));
    p5 = (dll*)malloc(sizeof(dll));

    p1->data = 1;
    p1->next = p2;

    p2->data = 2;
    p2->next = p3;

    p3->data = 3;
    p3->next = p4;

    p4->data = 2;
    p4->next = p5;

    p5->data = 1;
    p5->next = NULL;

    head = p1;

    printf("p1::%p\n", p1);
    printf("p2::%p\n", p2);
    printf("p3::%p\n", p3);
    printf("p4::%p\n", p4);
    printf("p5::%p\n", p5);
    printf("head::%p\n", head);

    for (temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next) {
        count++;
    }
    printf("no of nodes %d\n", count);

    temp = head;

    cur = temp;

    while (cur) {
        for (fwd = cur->next; fwd != NULL; fwd = fwd->next) {
            if (cur->data == fwd->data) {
                cur->next = fwd->next;
                // fwd->next=fwd->next->next;
                todel = fwd;
                free(todel);
                fwd = cur;
            }
        }
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    printf("p1::%p\n", p1);
    printf("p2::%p\n", p2);
    printf("p3::%p\n", p3);
    printf("p4::%p\n", p4);
    printf("p5::%p\n", p5);

    printf("p1->data::%d\n", p1->data);
    printf("p2 data::%d\n", p2->data);
    printf("p3->data::%d\n", p3->data);
    printf("p4->data::%d\n", p4->data);
    printf("p5->data::%d\n", p5->data);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
p1::0x8728008
p2::0x8728018
p3::0x8728028
p4::0x8728038
p5::0x8728048
head::0x8728008
no of nodes 5
temp::0x8728008
cur::0x8728008
no of nodes 1
p1::0x8728008
p2::0x8728018
p3::0x8728028
p4::0x8728038
p5::0x8728048
p1->data::1
p2 data::2
p3->data::3
p4->data::2
p5->data::0
```

By seeing the output (no of nodes :1) I know nodes got deleted but it's not that clear, I even don't know which node got deleted, still `p2` to `p4` are giving the same old data values, how would I know?

Comment: I think you have erased some code.I dont see any printf statements that will output 
**temp::0x8728008 cur::0x8728008 no of nodes 1**

Comment: Assuming your duplicate removal *worked*, you're dereferencing indeterminate pointers (`p5` and `p4` for ex). Once what they point to is `free()`d, their values (the same addresses that were stored in the linked list prior to the removals) become indeterminate. Dereferencing them invoke *undefined behavior*. Try printing the actual *list* (hint: write a function that prints a linked list given the `head`, then run it before, and after, your dupe-removal algorithm).

Comment: Generally speaking (without having groked your code), when you delete a node (and do not immediately dispose of it), the node may continue to contain links to adjacent nodes and hence cannot be used to determine if the node is indeed in the list.  To have otherwise the linked list *deleteNode* code must explicitly clear next/prior pointers in a deleted node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are erasing incorrect nodes, in the for-loop inner the while the `fwd` variable contain the **repeated node** and `cur` variable contain the **original node** (that is repeated). You are erasing the nodes between the **original node** and the **repeated node**. For erasing only the **repeated node** you need to maintain the node before this and set `last_fwd->next = fwd->next;`, this would erase only the repeated node (eg: `p4 and p5`, not `p1 or p2` if you need to erase this too is more work).

The other problem is you are printing the nodes using the pointers and not the `linked list` created. In that case when you erase `p4` and `p5` and try to print their value is undefined behavior (anything could happen, work, print garbage, reboot machine :D, etc...).

With the update code, the print is made using the links of the list. In this case the erased node are not touch.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct dll {
    int data;
    struct dll* next;
} dll;

int main() {
    dll* p1, *p2, *p3, *p4, *p5, *temp, *head, *todel, *cur, *fwd, *dup, *last_fwd;
    int count = 0, i = 0, j = 0;

    p1 = (dll*)malloc(sizeof(dll));
    p2 = (dll*)malloc(sizeof(dll));
    p3 = (dll*)malloc(sizeof(dll));
    p4 = (dll*)malloc(sizeof(dll));
    p5 = (dll*)malloc(sizeof(dll));

    p1->data = 1;
    p1->next = p2;

    p2->data = 2;
    p2->next = p3;

    p3->data = 3;
    p3->next = p4;

    p4->data = 2;
    p4->next = p5;

    p5->data = 1;
    p5->next = NULL;

    head = p1;

    printf("p1::%p\n", p1);
    printf("p2::%p\n", p2);
    printf("p3::%p\n", p3);
    printf("p4::%p\n", p4);
    printf("p5::%p\n", p5);
    printf("head::%p\n", head);

    for (temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next) {
        count++;
    }
    printf("no of nodes %d\n", count);

    temp = head;

    cur = temp;

    while (cur) {
        last_fwd = cur;
        for (fwd = cur->next; fwd != NULL; fwd = fwd->next) {
            if (cur->data == fwd->data) {
                last_fwd->next = fwd->next;
                todel = fwd;
                free(todel);
            }
            last_fwd = fwd;
        }
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    for (count = 0, temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next, count++) {
        printf("p%d::%p\n", count, temp);
        printf("p%d->data::%d\n", count, temp->data);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what are you doing at last, freeing the whole linked list? it's not the way you should implement it. actually there is no way to see if the chunk in heap is allocated or not(actually there is, but compiler-dependent and dirty). don't maintain linked list in this way.

`free` just put the memory back to the heap, it won't change the value of the pointer. as a C programmer, you should pay attension to the dynamic allocated memory is freed or not, since there is no standard way to help you out.

if you want to delete just the first link out of the list, you should do:

```
head = cur.next;
free(cur);
```

then forget about `cur`, you should never use it.

if you want to delete the link after `cur`, it roughly goes:

```
dll *tmp = cur->next;
cur->next = tmp->next;
free(tmp);
```

then never reference `tmp`.

Comment: I was trying to delete duplicate nodes, is this not the way :(? Please tell me then! I have no help from anywhere, learning on my own! It's so tough!